# Proving a fourier transform expression with green's formuls

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Using Green's formula, show that:

$${\cal F}\left[\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\right]= -w^2F(w) + \frac{e^{iwx}}{2\pi}\left(\frac{df}{dx} - iwf\right) \\(evaluated\ from\ -\infty\ to\ \infty)$$

last part is supposed to be evaluated from minus infiniti to plus infinity for the $e^{iwx}$ portion

So I tried to integrate out ${\cal F}\left[\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\right]$ and I was getting close, but not close enough...

Comment: Integration by parts two times gives the statement.

Comment: I was having trouble doing it the second time around. WHat is throwing me off is the portion that is being evaluated from $-\infty to \infty$ to I treat that as a constant and just attempt integration on the second portion again?

Comment: Yes. The general formula is $\int_a^b u v'dx = [uv]_a^b - \int_a^b u'vdx$. The term $ [uv]_a^b = u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a)$ is a constant. Here you would get $\mathcal{F}[f''] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f''(x) e^{iwx}dx = \left[\frac{f'e^{iwx}}{2\pi}\right]_{-\infty}^\infty - \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty iwf'(x) e^{iwx}dx$ its the last term you need to integrate by part again.

Comment: awesome. thanks.